# Definition of conflicting expression

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Under https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model, it is stated that

When an evaluation of an expression modifies a memory location and another evaluation reads or modifies the same memory location, the expressions are said to conflict. A program that has two conflicting evaluations has a data race unless

1. both evaluations execute on the same thread or in the same signal handler, or
2. both conflicting evaluations are atomic operations (see std::atomic), or
3. one of the conflicting evaluations happens-before another (see std::memory_order).

I am only referring to the 3rd statement.

```cpp
std::atomic<int> x = 0;
int y;
int z;
std::jthread th1([&]{
    y = 1;
    x.store(1, std::memory_order_release);
});
std::jthread th2([&]{
    z = (z++, ((x.load(std::memory_order_acquire) == 1) ? y : 0));
});
```

Assume that `x.load(std::memory_order_acquire)` does indeed give 1.
The full-expression `z = (z++, ((x.load(std::memory_order_acquire) == 1) ? y : 0))` conflicts with `y = 1` since both of them contain `y`, and also thread 1 modifies `y`.

Additionally, the evaluation of `z++` does not happen-before `y = 1`.

So purely based on the C++ reference's definitions, is this a data race?

Comment: the first argument of `?:` is sequenced before the evaluation of the second and third arguments.

Comment: Yes, but how about the full-expression as a whole? I guess my question is the standard does not make clear the granularity of conflicting expressions.

Comment: that doesn't matter.  The standard doesn't talk about full expressions here but individual expressions.

Comment: Is a full-expression not an "individual expression"? Yeah I get this is very pedantic as this is tagged a language lawyer question.

Comment: a full expression is usually everything up to the `;`.  an expression is all the little bits that make up the full expression.  for instance `++a = foo++;` is 3 expressions making up one full expression.  all of these have a sequence in which they will run and in this case `++a` happens first, then `foo++`, and then the assignment happens to the return of `a++` with the value returned from `foo++`.

Comment: I see what you mean, that the "evaluation of an expression" refers to a single "level of evaluation" in an AST sense, i.e. the evaluation of an expression from its immediate subexpressions, given that the immediate subexpressions have already completed their own evaluation.

Comment: @NathanOliver _`++a = foo++;` is 3 expressions_ Not 5?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I count 3 expressions.  How do you get 5?

Comment: @NathanOliver _id-expression_ (`a` or `foo`) is also an expression, no?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Oh yeah, forgot about those.